# string search in c from a http GET request

Tags: c, string, search

how to extract a specific string from an array of characters?

[image]

in my case buff contain what's shown in the image and i want to copy the file name 'hi.jpg' to another array of char, keep in mind that the file name will change depending on the http request sent by the browser.

Comment: What have you done so far?  How did it go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strstr(buff,"GET ")` and `strstr(buff," HTTP/1.1")` to find the start end end pos, then use `strncpy` to copy whats in between.